# Running an Excel VBA script

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm completely new to Excel and VBA, and received some old code that needs to run, but I'm unclear on exactly where I go to run it. It's likely just a menu item I can't find...but I'm also unclear on how these would run -- does the process happen continuously in the background when new cells are added? Or would I be manually running this every time I need it?

```
Sub CopyData()   
Dim lRow As Long   
Dim RepeatFactor As Variant   

lRow = 1   
Do While (Cells(lRow, "A") <> "")   

    RepeatFactor = Cells(lRow, "B")   
    If ((RepeatFactor > 1) And IsNumeric(RepeatFactor)) Then   

       Range(Cells(lRow, "A"), Cells(lRow, "B")).Copy   
       Range(Cells(lRow + 1, "A"), Cells(lRow + RepeatFactor - 1, "B")).Select   
       Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown   

       lRow = lRow + RepeatFactor - 1   
    End If   

    lRow = lRow + 1   
Loop 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no worries, we all start somewhere.

If you right click on your worksheet (in the bottom left hand corner) a menu comes up.
Then click "view code": the VBA Editor will pop up. Right click on the name of your project in the project tree on the left hand side and "insert a module".
Copy and paste that code into the module.

To run the code, try inserting a shape into your excel document, right click it, then click "assign macro" and select "CopyData"

Comment: also this is a great place to start:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> I'm also unclear on how these would run -- does the process happen continuously in the background when new cells are added? Or would I be manually running this every time I need it?

These depend on what you're actually trying to accomplish. If you need it to run every time something happens, you can set up VBA to do this -- by directing it to run code when certain events occur (like the selection changing).